# Openfire 4.3.2 Stream Managment not Working Propelry

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

I am Using openfire 4.3.2 as my XMPP chat server and my issue is when I Suddenly Close the app and after a few seconds later when I am again opening the app I didn't get those messages(send in those few seconds when my app is closed) here is my Server's properties.

```
httpbind.CORS.domains   *
httpbind.CORS.enabled   true
httpbind.enabled    true
httpbind.forwarded.enabled  false
log.debug.enabled   true
passwordKey     hidden
plugin.callback_on_offline.debug    true
plugin.callback_on_offline.send_body    true
plugin.callback_on_offline.token    884d8014-006f-4495-8290-7b53801c8f89
plugin.callback_on_offline.url  http://ec2-*-***-***-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/user/offline/message
plugin.userservice.secret   WjVSdHFw
provider.admin.className    org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.DefaultAdminProvider
provider.auth.className     org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.DefaultAuthProvider
provider.group.className    org.jivesoftware.openfire.group.DefaultGroupProvider
provider.lockout.className  org.jivesoftware.openfire.lockout.DefaultLockOutProvider
provider.securityAudit.className    org.jivesoftware.openfire.security.DefaultSecurityAuditProvider
provider.user.className     org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.DefaultUserProvider
provider.vcard.className    org.jivesoftware.openfire.vcard.DefaultVCardProvider
register.inband     true
register.password   hidden
sasl.mechs.00002    PLAIN
sasl.scram-sha-1.iteration-count    4096
stream.management.active     true
update.lastCheck    1556532896226
xmpp.auth.anonymous     true
xmpp.client.idle    600000
xmpp.client.idle.ping   true
xmpp.domain     18.224.19.131
xmpp.filetransfer.enabled   true
xmpp.server.session.allowmultiple   false
xmpp.server.session.idle    600000
xmpp.server.session.timeout     600000
xmpp.session.conflict-limit     1
xmpp.socket.ssl.active  true
```

I am using Smack 4.3.2 in my android code.
I have Noticed one thing if I didn't close the app just Close the Connection and after reconnection, everything Work Fine but If I close the app I am not Getting the message. How can I Solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two possible reasons.
One thing you should definetly do, is close the connection right when the app closes. Theres kind of an onClose function for it. Since the connection could still be available for a bit or it's idling.

The other reason(which i don't belive in), I have an option in my openfire interface where I can chose how offline-messages are handled. So there must also be a property for your version.

Also there is a bug with keepalive mechanism. Please check this:

https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-963

Issue is reported for version 4.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem might be this config parameter or openfire ghost session exists:

> xmpp.client.idle    600000 (10 minutes)

This is the client idle timeout where client will be disconnected if server did not ping the client succesfully. You should rethink the value of this parameter and bring it down to reasonable value suitable for your needs. For me it is 30 seconds. After that client gets disconnected, and all messages go to offline storage if offline messages are enabled.

Also there is a bug with keepalive mechanism. Please check this:

https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-963

Issue is reported for version 4.0.3.